# How to make a slow walking burn more calories?

Tags: running, walking, jogging, resistancetraining, resistance-cord

I walk with my kid. If I walk at her speed, I cannot exercise enough. If she runs with me, she cannot last long. If I run and she walks, she is out of my sight and may be dangerous. I am looking for a way to increase walking intensity, so I can walk with her speed, but burn more calories like running, and I still sweat and quickly breath.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some moving exercises like every 100m do 20 lunges, or high knees, or side step jumps keep walking on her pace like an active rest and repeat every 100m or every 2-3min. For example when you reach the 3min point you start skiping next to her for 20-30 sec then you can go to lunges for 20-30 seconds then you can go bunny style jumps for 20-30 sec and then you can go side step jumps for 20-30 sec each side.

This will definitely increase your heart rate, plus it will add some fun for your kid. You can ask her help on counting the reps or the seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Try some wrist and or ankle weights - or even a weight vest depending on the climate. You aren't quite going to get the same effect as if you were moving faster but you are going to be making it more effort for a given speed.

Comment: I advise against body weights used for long periods of time (increments greater than 10 min) because they are really bad for your joints and can asymmetrically affect muscles. Otherwise they are ok for short durations

Comment: Thank you very much. My fault to forget to mention I have tried it, and it caused joint and ankle pain, as Ace Cabbie mentioned.

Comment: @Superuser Ahh, apologies, yeah as Ace says it can be an issue :( A more distributed load such as vest can be better in those scenarios but if you've experienced pain in joints then it might not be a good idea to add more load to them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Go hiking? It's a lot of work for an adult to gain elevation, but your kid will scamper up ahead of you.